# How to upgrade/update minor version of composer via Terraform?

Tags: terraform, google-cloud-composer

I just recently created on my terraform base module a **composer environment instance** (`resource google_composer_environment`) with the following attribute : `image_version = "composer-2.0.30-airflow-2.3.3"`.

When you try to upgrade via the console, the cluster is not destroyed (I think?), but when I try to do it via terraform using `image_version = "composer-2.0.32-airflow-2.3.4"` the environment will apparently be scrapped and recreated :

```
# module.dev-omni-orchestrator-instance.google_composer_environment.omni-orchestrator-instance must be replaced
...
Plan: 1 to add, 0 to change, 1 to destroy.
```

Is there a way to achieve these version upgrade within terraform without destroying the existing environment? Perhaps upgrade via the **console** or **gcloud** and then update+import somehow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue previously, to solve it :

- Upgrade the version from the `Cloud Composer` `console`, in this case the cluster will not be destroyed
- Upgrade the version in your `Terraform` code
- When you will plan your `Terraform` `Composer` resource, `Terraform` will detect a change in the real infrastructure and will no plan change and nothing to update (because the version from the real infra is the same than in the Terraform resource)

I think it's an issue of the resource in the `Google provider` but it was not blocking for me with this technique.

Comment: @Imad have your solved your issue ?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I am currently testing it as updating the cluster takes a bit of time. FYI, while updating, I still get `Plan: 1 to add, 0 to change, 1 to destroy.` when I also update my terraform files with the new version. Will see after the update completes

Comment: Indeed ! This works well. Thank you 

` # module.dev-omni-orchestrator-instance.google_composer_environment.omni-orchestrator-instance has changed` but it is not destroyed, only updated in the state file!